# Could a nomogram be built from meta-regression coefficients?

Tags: regression-coefficients, meta-analysis, rms, meta-regression

I'm trying to build a nomogram from meta-regression co-efficients. The meta-regression model is done using the metafor package. However, I would like to represent the results into a nomogram. The RMS package only utilizes models fit in RMS. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried using this package or similar ones? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nomogramFormula/nomogramFormula.pdf